# Unable to execute LUIS Action Binding (Nodejs)

Tags: node.js, azure-language-understanding, azure-bot-service

I am making a service Bot. In the intent 'CustomerSatisfaction', I want 'rating' and 'future' as my mandatory entities and 'timetaken' as my optional entity. I have taken the format from internet and modified it according to my use case.

Issue:

I am not able to understand that how should I integrate this with my Bot's code, so that it could be executed. So, when I ask 'How did you like the service?', it goes to 'CustomerSatisfaction', intent and do not proceed further till user answers 'Please provide the rating out of 5 for this bot.', 'Please provide the rating out of 5 for this bot.' and where timetaken entity is optional.

[link](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-CognitiveServices/blob/master/Node/samples/LuisActionBinding/README.md) to which I have referred.

Here is the modified code according to my use case I want to integrate with my Bot's code. :

```
var CustomerSatisfactionAction = {
intentName: 'CustomerSatisfaction',
friendlyName: 'Customer Satisfaction',
confirmOnContextSwitch: true, // true by default
// Property validation based on schema-inspector - 
https://github.com/Atinux/schema-inspector#v_properties
schema: {
    rating: {
        type: 'any',
        rating : rating ,
        message: 'Please provide the rating out of 5 for this bot.'
    },
    future: {
        type: 'string',
        future : future ,
        message: 'Please provide the rating out of 5 for this bot.'
    },

    timetaken: {
        type: 'string',
        optional: true
    },
},

// Action fulfillment method, recieves parameters as keyed-object 
(parameters argument) and a callback function to invoke with the fulfillment 
result.fulfill: function (parameters, callback)
{
    session.send ('ok');
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to provide more information about what you're trying to accomplish and what specific problem you're having. What is your desired result versus what is the actual result you're getting? What do "future" and "timetaken" mean as entities? Why isn't the rating a numeric type? Did you make the "future" message a duplicate of your "rating" message?

Comment: Do you still need help?